# Railties in Rails 2.3 project?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I've inherited a small Rails project from a new client and unfortunately the previous developer(s) left essentially no information other than the Rails app instance running in production.  (No source repository, no documentation, just the login to the production server.)

Inspecting the server shows Rails version 2.3.8 installed (confirmed by the version number in "config/environment.rb") but when I try to run "ruby script/console" (or "server") on my local dev environment I get (essentially fatal) error messages originating from files in "`vendor/rails/railties`" and searching the internet for "railties" shows a lot of Rails 3 documentation.

I'm guessing that a previous developer/maintainer crossed the Rails 2/3 streams somehow.  Should I be ok to just delete the entire "`vendor/rails`" directory or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What kind of error are you getting? Do you know that your local environment is the same as production? Do other Rails 2.3.8 projects run fine on your machine?

Now, I think it should be fine to remove `vendor/rails` with the exception being that if the previous developer monkeypatched something in Rails, but *directly* in the `vendor/rails` directory. Then, you might have a problem.

This approach might be a bit tedious, but I might go as follows:

- Clone 2.3.8 somewhere else on my machine.
- Check it in to some form of version control.
- Copy your version of 2.3.8 from the project into the newly cloned directory.
- Diff it.

This should show you if the previous developer made any changes, both significant and insignificant, to Rails.

Good luck, because this doesn't sound very fun :(

Comment: +1 thanks for the advice, yes, I've setup a clean Rails 2.3.8 on a new dev VM and have put the project under source control but am tempted to just get to the point where I can run the tests, that might be an easier way to determine if I need to diff Rails itself...

Comment: @maerics Definitely don't disagree with you there. My thought was that if it bombs when trying to start `console` or `server`, was that it would "equally bomb" when trying to run the tests.

Comment: yeah, there's an entirely different set of errors running the tests (even trying to run "rake db:migrate"); hmm, this project might not be in the cards after all...

Comment: @maerics Out of curiosity, what did you end up doing?

Comment: after two full days of just trying to get a working dev environment (without success) I contacted the consultancy that placed me and told them the situation: basically we need a previous developer to give me a working snapshot of the project, the existing one has too many conflicting dependencies (found more Rails 2/3 mixups) and I'm sure the client would rather pay me to add the new features they need instead of reverse engineering someone else's non-working env.